# Android draw on screen from file

Tags: android

I have a file on my android device that is located at /storage/emulated/0/Movies/highscore.dat

I am trying to draw this (it contains string values) on the screen but I haven't found any solutions for this.

I've tred this but it just prints the location.

```
   File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
    File file = new File(path, "/" + "highscore.dat");
```

What should I do?

Comment: what are you trying to get the text inside the file or something else ?

Comment: Everything the file contains .

It symbolizes a top score - but it's string

Comment: Ok, when you say everything that may contain things that you don't want to show

Comment: Oh okay. Well, I just meant that I wanted everything the file contains to be drawn on the screen. It's just a single line the file contains, so that's why I want everything to be drawn :)

Comment: ok Charles, I did write some code but I am sure this is something you might not want, I believe you should get data in the file in some format so you can manipulate that in code like JSON/XML

Comment: oh ... well, yes possibly. 

Just answered to your post but now I see that it's not something I was looking for.

Thanks for the help. I'll try a different approach now

Answer (score 1):

have this in your layout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>
```

this is how you can read the entire data which is in the file

```
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path of your file")));
```

now that you have the text, all you have to do is populate it in `TextView`

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

textView.setText(""+text);
```

Comment: It cannot resolve method "findViewById" and readAllBytes

I did what you wrote but I get these errors :/

Comment: i am sorry, there was some mistake with the case, I have updated the answer, it should be  **findViewById**, Kindly check it

Comment: This seems like the right answer, so I don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: well it is right code Should you only want to print the text in a file to the screen but apparently if you have some formatted Text which has some purpose like **JSON/XML**, printing the entire text does not make sense. if the Data inside has some meaning to it, so it should be read and manipulated accordingly to only get useful data